# Using strings instead of enums?

Tags: c#, methods

Is it common place to use a string for comparison as opposed to an enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least, the strings should be declared as constants (or perhaps `readonly` fields) somewhere, instead of spread out through the code. However, this looks like the schoolbook example for when to use an `enum`.

```
public enum ObjectType
{
   UAV,
   Entity,
   // and so on
}
```

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk, This answers the core question - how to reduce replication though?

Comment: @WulfgarPro: you could look into @Felice's idea with [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Comment: And I disagree about Abstract Factory. How to can it be used here? Maybe you mean simple Factory or just a factory method?

Comment: It seems based on the OP that he only has strings to work with which would basically rule out enums unless you want to start working with Enum.GetName() etc. or am I missing something?

Comment: @Restuta: in this case I that the `DoSomeWork` method that you suggest in your answer is quite enough, since the two presented cases are acted upon in an identical manner.

Comment: Apologies but -1. Based on the original question "Using strings as flags?" and the context supplied I dont see how this answer could be considered correct? "looks like the schoolbook example for when to use an enum" is actually incorrect as we're dealing with strings. How would using enums in this situation alleviate the problems within the original code?

Comment: @bic: no need to apologise for the downvote when you have the courtesy of explaining why. My intention was simply to answer the question *"Is it common place to use a string as a comparison tool for this kind of situation?"*. I can't see anything in the question suggesting that the OP is restricted to using strings here, hence my suggestion to use enums. I agree this does not solve the other problems in the code.

Answer (score 6):

I am aware about your context, but as a first step you can just refactor this way:

**Step 1**

```
if (typeOfObject == "UAV")
{
    DoSomeWork(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForUavs);
}
else if (typeOfObject == "Entity")
{
    DoSomeWork(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForEntities);
}

private void DoSomeWork(IAgStkObject agStkObject)
{
    IAgStkObject stkObject = agStkObject.CurrentScenario.Children[stkObjectName];
    IAgDataProviderGroup group = (IAgDataProviderGroup)stkUavObject.DataProviders["Heading"];
    IAgDataProvider provider = (IAgDataProvider)group.Group["Fixed"];
    IAgDrResult result = ((IAgDataPrvTimeVar)provider).ExecSingle(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForUavs.CurrentTime);

    stkObjectHeadingAndVelocity[0] = (double)result.DataSets[1].GetValues().GetValue(0);
    stkObjectHeadingAndVelocity[1] = (double)result.DataSets[4].GetValues().GetValue(0);
}
```

Then consider replasing if's with switch:

**Step 2**

```
switch (typeOfObject)
{
    case "UAV":
        DoSomeWork(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForUavs);
        break; 
    case "Entity":
        DoSomeWork(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForEntities);
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException():
}
```

This can be even better when using enums.

Comment: Step 2a: consider replacing if/switch with virtual method if you getting more then 2 choices. See http://www.rosscode.com/blog/index.php?title=code_smell_switch_statements&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Restuta's answer, I'd use a

```
IDictionary<MyEnumifiedString, Action<IAgStkObject>>
```

to get rid of that if.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with @Frederik that this seems a perfect case for using enums, but it could be that the only thing you can get out of the application is a string. In which case your example is perfectly OK.

Oh yes - and make sure you have the string constants defined in one place, preferably a config file so that if they change the other application you don't have to recompile yours.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question I will always use a defined type to store the strings simply to have one location for change if needed.

So for your example i would have the following

```
public sealed class RootTypes
{
    public const string Entity = "entity";
    public const string UAV = "uav";
}
```

Your code then updates to this

```
    typeOfObject = typeOfObject.ToLower();
    if (typeOfObject == RootTypes.UAV)
    {
        stkUavObject = _stkObjectRootToIsolateForUavs.CurrentScenario.Children[stkObjectName];
        var group = (IAgDataProviderGroup) stkUavObject.DataProviders["Heading"];
        var provider = (IAgDataProvider) group.Group["Fixed"];
        IAgDrResult result = ((IAgDataPrvTimeVar) provider).ExecSingle(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForUavs.CurrentTime);
        stkObjectHeadingAndVelocity[0] = (double) result.DataSets[1].GetValues().GetValue(0);
        stkObjectHeadingAndVelocity[1] = (double) result.DataSets[4].GetValues().GetValue(0);
    }
    else if (typeOfObject == RootTypes.Entity)
    {
        IAgStkObject stkEntityObject = _stkObjectRootToIsolateForEntities.CurrentScenario.Children[stkObjectName];
        var group = (IAgDataProviderGroup) stkEntityObject.DataProviders["Heading"];
        var provider = (IAgDataProvider) group.Group["Fixed"];
        IAgDrResult result = ((IAgDataPrvTimeVar) provider).ExecSingle(_stkObjectRootToIsolateForEntities.CurrentTime);
        stkObjectHeadingAndVelocity[0] = (double) result.DataSets[1].GetValues().GetValue(0);
        stkObjectHeadingAndVelocity[1] = (double) result.DataSets[4].GetValues().GetValue(0);
    }
```

The issue of code redundancy has been anserwed by Restuta

Comment: ToLower() is kind of clunky and not 100% supported by all languages. You're better off using string.Equals(string1, string2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) to get a case-invariant equals.

Answer (score -2):

Use enums with bit flags:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFlags
{
    SomeFlag = 0x1, // 001
    OtherFlag = 0x2,// 010
    ThirdFlag = 0x4 // 100
}

var firstObject = MyFlags.SomeFlag;
var secondObject = MyFlags.SomeFlag | MyFlags.OtherFlag;

if(((int)secondObject & MyFlags.SomeFlag) != 0) 
{
    // true
}

if(((int)secondObject & MyFlags.OtherFlag) != 0) 
{
    // true
}

if(((int)firstObject & MyFlags.SomeFlag) != 0) 
{
    // true
}

if(((int)firstObject & MyFlags.OtherFlag) != 0) 
{
    // false
}
```

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) would be helpful.

Comment: Bitflags end up biting you.  
 - What happens when you declare another flag, but you'd like it to be between 0x1 and 0x2 ?